# What are these huge arrays filled with random characters doing within my browsers memory?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, out-of-memory

I'm running into memory issues with a site I'm developing using React. I am running out of memory occasionally and almost randomly. Looking at the memory usage, I can see that some weird things are happening with my site. There is too many potential problems that could be happening, so I was looking for help with one specific problem.

I seem to have multiple arrays filled with language characters (chinese, english) and arrays filled with characters I've never seen before.

[image]

These arrays are popping up more than once within my memory usage, between the 'Objects' and 'Arrays'

[image]

Here is a picture of the overall memory heap I thought may be helpful:
[image]